# How to alter CSS properties using PHP based on a conditional

Tags: php, mysql, css, sql

I'm working on a website that manages food. Keeping track of expiration dates and the such.

When a users dashboard loads, it shows a list of the food items they've currently added along with info about them, Brand, Location (Fridge,Pantry,Freezer), and expiration date.

I have the items in a html table, drawing their values from php echos of the rows of a food table I created.

What I want to do is change the text of the expiration date to red when there is about a 3 day difference between the current date and the set expiration date.

Here's my code for putting the values in the table.

```
       <?php 

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))

    {
?> 

            <tr>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Name'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Brand'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Type'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Container'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['ExpirationDate'] ?></td>
              </tr>


            <?php

    }
    ?>
```

$sql2 holds a query of all the foods owned by the user.

So how would I create a conditional that would make this work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = $rows['ExpirationDate'];
$difference = $date1->diff($date2);
$days = $difference->d;
$class = '';
if ($days <= 3)
    $class = 'class="expired"';
```

Then add the `$class` variable to each table cell. If the difference between dates is 3 days or less, it will add `class="expired"` otherwise it will add nothing. Then just style the `.expired` class to have red text.

You will most likely have to format your `$date2` variable, but how to do that depends on the format it's currently in...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a different class to the expiration date when it's getting close.

Something like:

```
<td><b><?php 
     $exptime = strtotime($rows['ExpirationDate']);
     if ($exptime - time() < 3*24*60*60){
         $class = 'expBad';
     }else{
         $class = 'expOK';
     }

     echo "<span class=\"$class\">".$rows['ExpirationDate']."</span>" ?></td>
```

Then in your .css you can define the class *expBad* to be red.

```
   span.expBad {
      color: red;
   }
```